# Determine if conversion from string to 32-bit integer will overflow

Tags: javascript, integer-overflow

Trying to do front-end validation on an HTML input instead of throwing an exception in the Java back-end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if ((the_number >> 0) != the_number) {
  // overflow...
}
```

You still need a server-side check because the client-side may turn off Javascript, etc.

Comment: @KennyTM - if someone has only worked with JavaScript and Java, they might not be familiar with lower level operations like bit shifts -- could you flesh out an explanation of what you're doing?  OP doesn't know enough to work out what 32-bit overflow would look like, so an explanation would probably help.

Comment: I am familiar with 32-bit overflow.  does javascript explicitly use 32-bit integers, or is this open to implementation?

Comment: @user: 11.7.2 The Signed Right Shift Operator: "The result is a signed 32-bit integer." (Ref: http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/ECMA-262.pdf)

Answer (score 2):

Check whether the number is more than `2147483647`.

For example:

```
if (parseInt(num, 10) > 2147483647)
    //BAD!!!
```

Comment: Good -- might be worth mentioning that you *must* do input validation on the Java back end as well as the front end.

Comment: @SLaks: Perhaps you need to check the lower bound (-2147483648) as well.

Comment: it is signed, so all of the above apply.  why didn't I think of this?

Answer (score 0):

Just check:

```
if (parseInt(myNumberAsString, 10) > 2147483647) {  alert("Invalid int!"); }
```